# Keep a view state/aspect after rotation

Tags: android, gridview, android-adapter

In my application I populate a GridView's adapter with random data from a file. The data is shown to the user as a TextView per item. If the user touch an item, the item changes the background colour.

The problem is that if the user touches an item and then rotates the device, the item returns to its original aspect (with the normal background colour)

I've tried different approaches:

- Implementing my own adapter
- Extending BaseAdapter
- Using ArrayAdapter
- Using selectors for the TextView
- Extending the TextView item with custom styles (from [here](http://charlesharley.com/2012/programming/custom-drawable-states-in-android/) and [here](http://code.neenbedankt.com/example-of-custom-states-in-android-components/))
- Disabling the View within the GridView's `onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)`

What I want to do is keep the Views' colour/style/aspect when I rotate the device

**Note**:

Why I load data radomly from a file?

The file contains different words. Every time the player start the activity (it is a game) different words in random order are shown inside the GridView. The user hast to point to the right word. If the user make a mistake, the word changes the colour (indeed, I prefer to disable the View). The process is repeated till the user makes the right choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the selected states of your list using onSaveInstanceState.

As you click on an item in your list you can assign a state to a boolean array.

Implement the onSaveInstanceState method in your Fragment/Activity.

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  outState.putBooleanArray(BundleArgs.STATES, mAdapter.getStates());
```

}

And then in onCreateView you pass those values to your adapter.

```
 if (savedInstanceState != null) {   
     states = savedInstanceState.getBooleanArray(BundleArgs.STATES);
   //Declare adapter and pass states to it
   myAdapter = new Adapter(context, values, states);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a mistake I've seen several times repeated on SO.

The `data` and the `view` that represents the data are **totally different** entities and they should be treated separately.

You need to keep the state of your data in another data element and preserve that data element during rotation. For example (it's just an example, there' several ways of doing it):

```
// possible states
private static final int NORMAL = 0;
private static final int RIGHT = 1;
private static final int WRONG = 2;
Map<String, Integer> states; // here you keep the states
```

then on every click, on the code that checks the answer and change color:

```
// process the click/state change
states.put(word, newState);
```

then on rotation:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putSerializable("states", states);
}
```

and on create

```
// onCreate
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
   states = (Map<String, Integer>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("states");
} else {
   states = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
}
```

and then back on your custom adapter you have to check the state and modify the view accordingly.

```
// inside getView
int state = 0
if(states.containsKey(word)){
   state = states.get(word).intValue();
}
switch(state){
   // deal with the cases and set the color
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, changing the TextView state is not the same that combine Data and View. Is that the mistake you referred?

Comment: The mistake is to use `View`s as a main reference of the data. That's because `View`s gets destroyed, rebuilt and recycled, specially when dealing with `ListView`s. So you need a total separate entity that holds the data, and set the view state accordingly.

Comment: But I didn't use the `View` as the reference of the data, did I?

Comment: But u forgot that it gets destroyed on rotation n you should 'remember' the state "data" yourself